# SQL Database and ArcSDE Database

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to have sql database and ArcSDE database running on the same server - virtual machine?  What are the benefits?  What are the negatives?

Answer (score 0):

As long as they are both `.mdf` files there shouldn't be any issue. Althought, ArcSDE is middle-ware, so you never query the SQL server directly, only through ArcSDE. (I might be wrong on that, you could also check out gis.stackexchange.com)